# Usar timestamp com identificador único num processo em PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

Esse é o cenário:

Um site de comércio que lida com muitas transações por segundo.
Está hospedado em computadores multi-core de alta performance na AWS.

Está sendo usada a função `time()` de php para gerar um identicador único da transação.

Eu não sei se nunca aconteceu por um simples acaso ou se pode acontecer, mas existe a possibildade de 2 ou mais usuários que estejam conectados no mesmo momento gerarem 2 ou mais identificadores semelhantes ?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, a chance de conflito é grande.
O ideal é que cada transação receba um identificador incremental único mas se isto não for possível, recomendo que utilize um prefixo com a identificação da máquina. Fica melhor ainda usando um hash.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

 $id = sha1($serverName.time());
```

Você ainda pode acrescentar mais informações como o Id da sessão.

Comment: Mas será que o algoritmo que vai gerar o hash tbm pode gerar dois ids semelhantes? veja o que está sendo fornecido: o servername (que é uma constantes e o time() que será o mesmo para 2 o mais usuários que se conectaram simultaneamente. Correto?

Comment: Sim, também existe o risco de colisão. É um sistema arriscado, mas você pode inventar algo que diminua este risco, combinando variáveis, como por exemplo os 10 primeiros caracteres do hash somados aos ultimos caracteres da sessão, somados a algo mais. O banco de dados é relacional ?

Comment: sim o banco de dados é relacional. O que eu costumo fazer num cenário desse é gerar um valor pseudo aleatório e antes de gravar eu verifico se esse valor já existe, Se sim gere outro valor novamente, Se não, grave no banco. O fato aqui  é que o boss ele quer que seja usado um timestamp mas eu estou colhendo argumentos para refutar essa abordagem.

Comment: O tema em questão é "colisão". Você encontrará números sobre isso.

Answer (score 0):

Se lida com muitas transações por segundo e utiliza `time()` então você tem muitas colisões por segundo, **naturalmente**. O `time()` retorna a data em unixtime, *que a quantidade de segundos contados desde 1970*.

Logo, você utiliza o `time()` para ser um identificador único então você apenas pode processar uma transação por segundo. Se no mesmo segundo duas transações forem processadas irá utilizar a mesma *data*, [veja este exemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c490c3ee717e25eb46525f616addd27aaffcd7b8).

O `microtime()` por sua vez informa os microssegundos, o que é menos pior, mas ainda sim existe risco, se não há nenhum tipo de bloqueio, de duas transações terem o mesmo identificador.

---

Se quiser um identificador único, ou mais próximo disto, utilize [CSPRNG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG), isto fará com que seja aleatório (*na verdade é determinístico, mas enfim*). A probabilidade de duas transações gerarem o mesmo conjunto de bytes é baixa, e é ainda menor se maior for o conjunto de bytes, como por exemplo:

```
$random_bytes = random_bytes(128);
```

Você pode utilizar `bin2hex`/`base64` ou `unpack` (que é preferível) para representar os bytes de alguma forma.

---

Se quiser retornar valores numéricos você pode utilizar:

```
implode('', unpack("N*", random_bytes(4)));
// Resultado: 555172730
// Resultado: 1360929444
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93d19cd1cccda0c0c9c9bf58da76a3de8d45bee3)

O `N` indica que é um *unsigned long (always 32 bit, big endian byte order)*, cada 32 bit (*4 Bytes*) representa uma sequencia numérica.

O `unpack` suporta outras representações, como o `H` que retorna em *hex*, cada 4 bits é equivalente a uma letra/número (de 0-9 e de A-F), faz exatamente o que o `bin2hex` faz, por exemplo:

```
unpack("H*", random_bytes(32))[1];
// Resultado: de2e461f0955d58dc4f6fbd55afafb779e976be781651d80832e91824fd22d35
// Resultado: 2688ffde028dc8893446912d057d388571e21dbcafe0c3185c5ec32d7f047f35
```

---

Comparação, simulando que executasse 4 transações por segundo (*uma transação a cada 250000 microssegundos*):

```
time():
1493901169
1493901169
1493901169
1493901170

random_bytes(4) + unpack(N):
930833536
883463788
1732194618
265243744

random_bytes(32) + unpack(H):
a679d799284b4c2e3483c1f457a6d5cf9a500d8b37ecdbc0f804fc614f167ea3
a461dff841f8e43a4c377e507e04a47d6fbd8980a0f46dbb9bcaf2678ebadeac
68bdd0709e3dc2460dadd3dccf25771d98f6665159186270c2869dcaf0e79942
c82dca8125a82925872261bf5fca8ff026b9d0546a39658d8cbdd3a2c5267d33
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da5a1e1a5a95cf23d6c8f063ebf6e9aad9f53510)